# Building a scalable xml bridge processing platform

Tags: tomcat, jetty, grizzly, throughput

I'm building middleware that receives a request from the Internet, 
connects to a locally available search platform and gets some XML back.

It then changes this XML, pruning it, and changing into some other format (probably JSON) and sends it back to the calling application.

I'm thinking of using the following technology stack to achieve this.

Tomcat + Plain old servlets

I want to get the throughput per box (quad-core, dual-cpu, 32GB ram) as high as possible, and I'm suspicious that tomcat might not be the best option and that I might be better off with a Jetty or a Grizzly or others I'm not aware of?  Does anyone have some comparison data or anecdotal evidence about which technology they would start with?

If not, I guess I should start by bench-marking them with my own test data set. *sigh*

Comment: It depends a lot on what your requests look like. Benchmarks about server scalability tend to emphasise the rate at which they can accept and serve requests for small responses. If your responses are large, so that raw transmission throughput is the dominant factor, then differences between different servers will be more muted.

Comment: Also, if you have a front-end webserver like nginx, which is widely considered sensible, then it will handle a lot of the grunt work of scaling - handling lots of connections, assembling requests coming in from a huge number of slow clients, trickling responses back out to those slow clients, even caching responses if possible - which eases the technical demands on the back-end. There, the time taken to actually do the work should dominate the time spent doing container work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleeding edge, but has some nice scaling metrics: [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RepoExpress)

If you can go non-java, you might want to consider [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)